# custom background colors for ActionBar items

Tags: android-actionbar, android

I have an ActionnBar for which I am trying to set the background color and I would like to change the background color of each items in the ActionBar with other color on "Tap".
This thing is not working for some reason. I have tried changing various options given in other topics.Nothing works not sure why. What is the right way to do it. I followed Android Developer website to do this and still is not reflected. Thanks for your time

My styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionBarButton</item>
         <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/circular_tap_state</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/custom_settings_button</item>
    </style>
```

custom_settings_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
</selector>
```

custom action bar - action_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/today"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_today"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_custom_calender_icon_normal_state"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_calendar" />


     <item
        android:id="@+id/add_event"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_custom_add"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_add" />

     <item
        android:id="@+id/calendar_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_custom_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Are you modifying styles.xml in values-v11 and values-v14?

Comment: nope I am not. I am just doing in styles in values.. do I need to do in v-11 and v-14 as well?

Comment: Yes you have to modify your styles file in v-11 and v-14 as well.